# Cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [6]' to Object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this assignment question since 3 days now and honestly, I ran out of solutions. 
I created the declaration of the class Plant,attribute type and I overloaded the == & != operators but I constantly getting the error message cannot convert argument 1 from const char [6] to Plant ? 
I'm not sure what I'm missing ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


 class Plant {
 private: 
 char* type[10];  //Declare the type attribute of type Char [10]

  Plant(char* type1[10]); //Declare the const type1 of Object Plant 

  bool operator==(const Plant &b) const
   {
       return ( (type ==b.type) );
   }
   bool operator!=(const Plant &b) const
    {
    return ( (b.type!=type) );
    }

    //overload the print function
    void print()
    { cout << type; 
     }

      };//end class Plant

      class Fruit: public Plant {
      public:
      char* taste [10];

       public:
       bool operator==(const Fruit& rhs) const
       {
         //return (taste == rhs.taste && type == rhs.type);
         return (taste == rhs.taste);
        }

        bool operator!=(const Fruit& rhs) const
        { return (taste != rhs.taste );
         //return (taste != rhs.taste && type != rhs.type);
        }

        void print()
        {printf("Hi Fruit");
         cout << taste; 
         } // print to know if I reached this part

         };//end class Fruit


          int main() {
          Plant a((char*)"Maple");
          a.print();
          Plant b("Maple");

           if (a == b)
           printf("a and b are equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and b are not equal\n");
           if (a != b)
           printf("a and b are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and b are equal\n");

           Fruit c("Apple","sweet");
           c.print();
           Fruit d("Apple","sweet");

           if (c == d)
           printf("c and d are equal\n");
           else
           printf("c and d are not equal\n");
           if (c != d)
           printf("c and d are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("c and d are equal\n");

           if (a == c)
           printf("a and c are equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and c are not equal\n");
           if (a != c)
           printf("a and c are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and c are equal\n");

            if (c == a)
            std::cout <<"c and a are equal\n"<< std::endl;
            else
            std::cout <<"c and a are not equal\n"<< std::endl;
            if (a != c)
            std::cout <<"c and a are not equal\n"<< std::endl;
            else
            std::cout <<"c and a are equal\n"<< std::endl;

           return 0;
           }
```

I'm new to C++ just started learning and I've read the following 
resources :

1. http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/relational.html
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ 
   and many other websites but I'm not allowed to post more than 2.

Any tip or help will be HIGHLY appreciated..

Thank you!

Comment: Recommendations: don't use `char *`, don't use `printf`.

Comment: @erip thanks for passing , I'll try to edit my code and hopefully get it right but just a side note we are required to add a code to the class Plant and Class Fruit . The main class shouldn't be touched its given.

Comment: All the member functions of `Plant` are private, including the constructor. So the `Plant` class can not be instantiated except by a member function of itself. The main function is not such a member.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks for commenting, well we were asked to initialize an a private attribute called type thats why I declare it to be private ..

Comment: Paul is saying that *everything* in `Plant` is private.

Comment: @Neil Sorry I misunderstood him

Comment: `char* type[10];  //Declare the type attribute of type Char [10]` - actually that little star is very important. Actually the type here is `char * [10]`. This means ten pointers to character. It means you plan to have 10 different locations in memory, each of which will store some characters.   I think you actually meant `char type[10]` everywhere you have written `char *   [10]`.  However you have so many other mistakes too.

Answer (score 1):

The errors here are due to misunderstandings about C-style strings, and would probably go away if you used `std::string`.

For example:

```
bool operator==(const Plant &b) const
{
   return ( (type ==b.type) );
}
```

This does **not** compare the two strings. It compares the pointers called `type`. You should use the `strcmp` function.

`char* type[10];` This does not create a string of 9 or 10 characters, which I assume is what you wanted. It is an array of 10 `char` pointers. I think you wanted `char type[10]`. This will reserve space for a string of **9** characters plus the null terminator. If you try to store more than this, your program will exhibit undefined behavior and you may not even get an error message.

`(char*)"Maple"` This is a C-style cast. Don't use them. Use `static_cast` and if the code doesn't compile, you are probably doing something wrong. Never add a cast "just to get it to compile".

Again I highly suggest you use `std::string` which works much more like the string types of other languages and has more safety.

Comment: Thank You Neil for taking the time to illustrate this to me. I really confused because there are ALOT of resources in the internet and some are just giving conflict information.. that's why I post my question here..

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code to use more idiomatic C++ constructs like `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Plant {
  public:
    Plant(std::string name) : type_(name) {}
    bool operator==(const Plant &that) const {
      return type_ == that.type_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Plant &that) const {
      return !operator==(that);
    }
    void print() { std::cout << type_ << std::endl; }
protected:
    std::string type_;
};

class Fruit: public Plant {
  public:
    Fruit(std::string name, std::string taste) : Plant(name), taste_(taste) {}
    bool operator==(const Fruit& that) const {
      return ((taste_ == that.taste_) && (Plant::operator==(that)));
    }

    bool operator!=(const Fruit& that) const {
      return !operator==(that);
    }

    void print() { Plant::print(); std::cout << taste_ << std::endl; }
  private:
    std::string taste_;
};


int main() {
  Plant a("Maple");
  a.print();
  Plant b("Maple");

  if (a == b) {
    std::cout << "a and b are equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "a and b are not equal" << std::endl;
  }

  Fruit c("Apple","sweet");
  c.print();
  Fruit d("Apple","sweet");

  if (c == d) {
    std::cout << "c and d are equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "c and d are not equal" << std::endl;
  }

  if (a == c) {
    std::cout << "a and c are equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "a and c are not equal" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
23:24 $ ./a.out 
Maple
a and b are equal
Apple
sweet
c and d are equal
a and c are not equal
```

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/zqoT3u).

Comment: Why doesn't `Fruit` compare the `type` as well? Its operators should call the parent ones.

Comment: OP's code doesn't compare strings properly either :p

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of the parent operators.

Comment: @erip THANK YOU So MUCH however, I have a question for you can I still compile the code without errors and without  changing anything in the main function ? I mean by keeping the same print function

Comment: Which `print` function?

Comment: @Everyone else: I fixed my edit. Shall we clean up comments?

Comment: You certainly can use `printf`, but it's recommended to use `std::cout` in C++ - it's up to you. The big thing is the use of `std::string` and some of the OO details.

Comment: @erip One more thing,  I was trying to play with the code to check if I can add another comparison like that between class fruit & class Plant but it throws an error message   if (c == a)
   std::cout <<"c and a are equal\n"<< std::endl; Do I need to add edit the == operator ?

Comment: If I create `Plant e("Apple")` and compare it to `c`, you'll see that they are equal with the code that I've written above.

Comment: @erip I add the comparasion to the original program I posted earlier

Comment: Fruits can be compared to fruits. Plants can be compared to plants and fruits. Order matters here. Please ask another question - this is a different issue.

Comment: @erip Aha, ok I'll post one soon but I should wait about 30 min to do so. mean while I'll try to understand the code and possible try to edit the equality operator to accept the comparasions

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of C++. I think you want to get rid of all those character arrays and char pointers now that you have stepped into the C++ realm. std::string is a very powerful encapsulation of all the basic string operations you may want to perform. Please refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for a complete API definition of the std::string class. Based on my understanding of what you want to accomplish, I have modified your program to use std::string. This program compiles and runs fine. Let me know if you have difficulties understanding the program and I can trake you through it. Also, please note the use of parameterized constructors and Initialization lists, the details of which you can find out on the same website I shared with you. I will be more than happy to help you with any aspect of writing a C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


 class Plant {
 private:
 std::string type;  //Declare the type attribute of type Char [10]

 public:
  Plant(std::string type1) : type(type1) {}//Declare the const type1 of Object Plant 

  bool operator==(const Plant &b) const
   {

       return (type == b.type);
   }
   bool operator!=(const Plant &b) const
    {
    return (b.type != type);
    }

    //overload the print function
    void print()
    {
       cout << type;
    }

      };//end class Plant

      class Fruit: public Plant {
      public:
      std::string taste;

       public:
       Fruit(std::string fruit, std::string t) : Plant(fruit), taste(t) {}
       bool operator==(const Fruit& rhs) const
       {
         //return (taste == rhs.taste && type == rhs.type);
         return (taste == rhs.taste);
        }

        bool operator!=(const Fruit& rhs) const
        { return (taste != rhs.taste);
         //return (taste != rhs.taste && type != rhs.type);
        }
        void print()
        {printf("Hi Fruit");
         cout << taste;
         } // print to know if I reached this part

         };//end class Fruit


          int main() {
          Plant a("Maple");
          a.print();
          Plant b("Maple");

           if (a == b)
           printf("a and b are equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and b are not equal\n");
           if (a != b)
           printf("a and b are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and b are equal\n");

           Fruit c("Apple", "sweet");
           c.print();
           Fruit d("Apple", "sweet");

           if (c == d)
           printf("c and d are equal\n");
           else
           printf("c and d are not equal\n");
           if (c != d)
           printf("c and d are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("c and d are equal\n");

           if (a == c)
           printf("a and c are equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and c are not equal\n");
           if (a != c)
           printf("a and c are not equal\n");
           else
           printf("a and c are equal\n");


           return 0;
           }
```

Comment: Thanks or your comment and offer to help I really appreciate it.